# Running race joinning with specific category or ticket

Tags: php, mysql, payment

I have now a PHP/MySQL website for signup and payment for running races.

My main problem (which blocks me now at all) is, an user sign up, and pay inscription for a single race. This single race has MySQL field "price". running race <-> single price.

In a month I will have a new event, and the organizer wants multiple prices for different runners (depending age, child, senior, etc)

My actual MySQL Schema is

```
USERS (**id**, username, password, email)
USER_PROFILES (user_id, name, surname, gender, birthdate, etc...)
EVENTS (**id**, name_desc, date, price, ...)
REGISTRATIONS (id, user_id, event_id, signup_date, bank_order, bank_result)
```

I imagine the user website flow, but I don't know how to implement it in DB.
The flow would be:
 - Types the spanish ID card.
 - The system check if it's joined previously.
 - If not, the user fills personal data form.
 - (New) **Click the category/ticket/price for this user.**
 - Adds the user to a "cart".
 - Pay all runners in single payment.

---

Ex: http://www.cronometrajes.com/en/guest_signup/race/ii_carrera_popular_olleros_de_sabero

Test ID: 71000000N

Spanish phone format: [0-9]{9} Ex: 666554433

---

Due to my website schema, I don't know how to improve my actual site with this other feature.

I hope I have explained everything perfect. Sorry about my bad English.

Comment: There is a 1 to 1 relation between users and profiles, right?

Comment: And (clearly!?!) event price now needs to be in its own table !!

Comment: The relationship /PHP tank auth) between users and profiles is 1:1)

Answer (score 0):

This is simple and you are almost there already. You know that you need multiple prices per event. Which means you need some sort of `event price list` object that relates to an event. Then you can have many prices per event.

So now you could create something like

```
event_price_list (id, event_id, max_age, price)
```

So this data would look like

```
id, event_id, max_age, price
1,  1,        10,        80
2,  1,        18,        100
3,  1,        21,        140 
4,  1,        60,        60
```

Now you can use the event table to get all event price lists and using age you could work out which price list you want. You could potentially create another table called `age_brackets` or something like that which would relate child, adult, senior to actual ages if you want and this could be referenced in your price list table or you could manage that in code. There are a couple of variations, but this should get you started.

Comment: Your first column is redundant

Comment: I prefer to have IDs on all my tables. I think it's a matter of preference. If I have a table that needs to reference this table for whatever reason it becomes a lot simpler. I wouldn't need to conjure up a composite primary key. You could remove it if you wanted I guess, but I would recommend to include it.

Comment: OK, but you're always going to reference (event_id, max_age)